# Add real time exchange rates to website

Tags: vb.net

I need to get real time exchange rates to my website and be able to get it's value for other calculations. I've searched online but could not find any tips.

Can anyone tell me how to import live rates to my website using vb.net? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at openexchangerates.com . I use this for a html project, with an ajax call you will receive an hourly updated JSON object with updated exchange rates.

A bit of googling will help how to import JSON with vb.net